# How can restore just one table from database backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I restore just one table from a database backup in SQL Server?

Comment: You cannot do this - not without extra tooling. Check out [Red-Gate Virtual Restore](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/) which allows you to "mount" a database backup - as if it were a live database - and with this, you could e.g. grab the data from that table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

A better option would be to `Generate Scripts` from the first original database, and choose 1 table, and `Script Data`. Then execute this script on your database (where you wish to restore just 1 table).

If you don't have access to the original database, then restore the backup to a new database, create the `Generate Scripts..` script from there, and then remove the new database.